# In which form the map of an ios navigation app is stored?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, plist

I am trying to draw a map in an ios app (using the points' coordinates from OpenStreetMap) and I have tried loading the data (i.e., cartesian coordinates of the map's points) both from a plist as well as from a simple text file but in both cases the loading is too slow. Does anybody know in which form the map in existing ios navigation apps is stored? Perhaps the storing using Core Data will be more efficient in terms of loading speed?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps it will be, but what you're doing shouldn't be slow for the use you describe. If you switch storage formats without knowing why your code is slow, you may repeat the same mistakes and end up with code that's different but still slow. You need to understand why you have the problem in the first place.

Comment: Dear Tom thank you for your response